# CAn't connect to server from SQL server Data tools

Tags: sql-server, server, ssis, database-connection, ssis-2012

I am not able to establish connection to Servers using the SSIS. It shows the following error
[Error it shows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cnaxZ.png)

`Error in words: "TITLE: Connection Manager`

Test connection failed because of an error in initializing provider. `Client unable to establish connection
TCP Provider: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.`
"

I have access to the **servers** and I am able to open it in `SQL Server`. I am using virtual machine to run the tool as I am using Mac.

Can anyone help me with the issue or is there any alternative for `SSIS tool` in `MacOs`?

Answer (score 0):

Which version of SQL Server are you using? If you are using SQL Server Express, it is configured to not allow remote connections by default. As you are running SSIS in a VM, it is a remote connection, even if the SQL Server instance is running on your Mac.

[How do I configure SQL Server Express to allow remote tcp/ip connections on port 1433?](http://support.webecs.com/kb/a868/how-do-i-configure-sql-server-express-to-allow-remote-tcp-ip-connections-on-port-1433.aspx)